# Does stating multiple degrees from a single university on a CV disadvantage an applicant for a research or lecturing position?

Tags: etiquette, postdocs, cv, degree, lecturer

I have a bit of a potentially unusual situation with my CV.  Over the years while I worked in an unrelated field (to pay the bills etc), I completed multiple degrees - all degrees were completed to a good standard.  The degrees are either in education (earlier ones) or physics (later ones).

However, most of the degrees are from a single university - including the final few, which were in closely related fields. All culminating in a PhD.

My question is - **is there any disadvantage to having multiple degrees listed from the same university on a CV when applying for a postdoc or lecturing position?**

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no disadvantage to having multiple degrees from the same university.  Normally you should not leave any degrees out of your CV.  There are advantages to having experience at multiple universities, but that does not have to be in the form of a degree.

Comment: Thank you for this reassurance - I had received conflicting advice about this.

Comment: @Saturnus It's something of a traditional belief in academia that staying at the same institute is something like "academic incest". Being at several universities is supposed to expose you to more cultures (of all meanings), research, and researchers.  Staying at one in this case is presumed to mean you are more narrow-minded (academically or otherwise), and less well-connected (fewer vectors for collaborations, fewer recommendations from researchers in your area, etc.) , and this is (deemed) an undesirable trait for a researcher. This is changing a bit (yay internet), though.

Comment: Wow... it's a good thing then that, as mentioned, it's not all of the degrees

Comment: @Saturnus - But z timmy might be overstating this.  Here's a way of looking at it: if we look at two otherwise equal candidates, and one has diversified to an additional university (which has a strong program), then the diversifier would have a plus that the other candidate doesn't.

Comment: Well it's a bit late now :(

Comment: @aparente001 if "diversification" means so much to you, OP has actually "diversified" much more than your hypothetical "diversifier" since he/she got multiple degrees in completely unrelated disciplines. Personally I think this "academic incest" notion is utter poppycock. If we look at two otherwise equal candidates and one has diversified to an additional university, then they are not just "otherwise equal", they are simply equal.

Comment: ... And I hold this opinion irrespectively of the fact that my three degrees are all from the same university.

Comment: @DanRomik - Your comment would make a helpful answer here.  There has been only one answer so far, which is diametrically opposed to the view you expressed in your comment.  (Please note, my position was somewhere *between* yours and Anonymous Physicist's -- closer to yours than to AP's.)

Comment: @aparente001 my view is essentially the same as that expressed in AnonymousPhysicist's answer (which I upvoted), and certainly not diametrically opposed to it, so I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @DanRomik - Hmm.  AnonymousPhysicist wrote, "There are advantages to having experience at multiple universities," and you wrote, "If we look at two otherwise equal candidates and one has diversified to an additional university, then they are not just 'otherwise equal', they are simply equal."  How are those statements in agreement?  Am I misunderstanding one of you?

Comment: @aparente001 there are "advantages" (and disadvantages) to doing almost anything (including staying at the same university for all your degrees). I think you tend to read a bit more into what I write than the literal meaning of my words. Anyway, hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @DanRomik - I think I may have been confusing the "traditional belief" described by zibadawa timmy with Anonymous Physicist's answer.  // It looks like we're both having trouble understanding the other today.   I was quite surprised when you wrote, "if 'diversification' means so much to you," since in my comment I was trying to say that I see diversification of institution as being of *minor importance*.

Comment: For clarity, if it's desired, I was not espousing the "academic incest" idea as either valid or invalid.  Just that such a perception does seem to exist in some academics, enough so that I have heard it myself on a number of occasions from several different tenured professors.  You can also see it reflected in some of Feynman's accounts of how he decided where to do his post-doctoral work (his advisor seemed to think it was a very bad idea for him to stay at the same university, and much better to go to a different one, which Feynman later agreed it was), which I think was not unusual then.